# Why does Symfony2 logs file specify a different time than the server time?

Tags: php, symfony, logging

So I have this Symfony3 web app that registers any error into `prod.log` (Symfony's default behaviour). It is around 2am local by the time of writing this post.

When I SSH to the server, I can see the time of the server:

[image]

But at the same time, logs in `prod.log` show a different time:

[image]

Where should I investigate to sync both times?

Comment: Somewhere your PHP app is setting a timezone, which is different from the hosting server.

Comment: @jszobody: Hi and thanks for joining in. Nowhere in my app there is `date_default_timezone_set()` defined. I also looked in `php.ini` and `;date.timezone =` is commented out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), what Symfony uses for logging by default, creates a `DateTimeImmutable` object [and adds it to the log record](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/03bbe04ba14dc812dfc2e243e45f640c08f9ff95/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L307-L322) for one of the handlers to pick up and format.

The logger [takes a timezone in its constructor](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/03bbe04ba14dc812dfc2e243e45f640c08f9ff95/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L144), falls back on the default timezone set in `php.ini` (which isn't set, per a comment on the original post), and falls back to UTC as a last resort.

What's likely happening is the Monolog timezone is being set to UTC, but your server is something else. There's no configuration option in the monolog bundle to set the timezone, so your best bet to set the timezone you want in `php.ini`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for your detailled explanation!